# Unable to access value of HiddenField which is inside GridView

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net, gridview

I am setting the value of HiddenField which is inside GridView using Jquery.

```
$(this).siblings('input[type="hidden"]').val(roundedvalue);
```

But I am unable to access the same using

```
HiddenField hidn= (HiddenField)gvdtaxes.Rows[2].FindControl("hidnin");
```

`hidn.Value` is always blank `""`  although it had a value when I checked using inspect element in Chrome.

**Markup**

```
<asp:GridView ID="gvdtaxes" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
                         CssClass="tabledata">
                         <Columns>
                            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="SrNo">
                      <ItemTemplate>
                    <%# Container.DataItemIndex + 1 %>
                </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
                             <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Tax Type">
                                 <ItemTemplate>
                                     <asp:Label ID="lbltaxtype" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("TaxCode") %>'></asp:Label>
                                 </ItemTemplate>
                             </asp:TemplateField>
                             <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Tax Description">
                                 <ItemTemplate>
                                     <asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Description") %>'></asp:Label>
                                 </ItemTemplate>
                             </asp:TemplateField>
                             <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Tax Value">
                                 <FooterTemplate>
                                     <asp:TextBox ID="txtftrtaxvalue" runat="server" class="totaltaxvalue"></asp:TextBox>
                                     <br />
                                     <asp:TextBox ID="txtftrfinalamount" runat="server" class="finalamount"></asp:TextBox>
                                 </FooterTemplate>
                                 <ItemTemplate>
                                     <asp:TextBox ID="txttaxvalue" runat="server" class="taxvalue"></asp:TextBox>
                                     <asp:FilteredTextBoxExtender ID="Filteredtaxvalue" runat="server" 
                                         FilterType="Numbers, Custom" TargetControlID="txttaxvalue" ValidChars="." />
                                     <asp:HiddenField ID="hidnin" runat="server" />
                                 </ItemTemplate>
                             </asp:TemplateField>
                         </Columns>
                     </asp:GridView>
```

**Javascript**

```
function CalculateTaxes() {
            var taxvaluesum = 0;
            $(".taxvalue").each(function () {
                //add only if the value is number               

                if (!isNaN(this.value) && this.value.length != 0) {
                    taxvaluesum += parseFloat(this.value);
                }
                else {
                    $(this).val('0')
                }
            });
            //$('.totaltaxvalue').val(taxvaluesum.toFixed(2));
            $('.totaltaxvalue').attr("value", taxvaluesum.toFixed(2));
            var finalamt = parseFloat($('.totaltaxvalue').val()) + parseFloat($('#ContentPlaceHolder1_Gridview1_txtftrvalue').val());
            $('.finalamount').attr("value", finalamt.toFixed(2));
            //$('.finalamount').val(finalamt.toFixed(2));
        }


        $(document).on('blur', ".taxvalue", function (e) {
            CalculateTaxes();
            var roundedvalue = parseFloat($(this).val()).toFixed(2);
            $(this).val(roundedvalue);

            $(this).siblings('input[type="hidden"]').val(roundedvalue);
            $('#<%=hidnout.ClientID %>').val(roundedvalue);
            alert($('#<%=hidnout.ClientID %>').val());
            //document.getElementById().value = roundedvalue;

            //alert($(this).siblings('input[type="hidden"]').val());



        });
```

**Code Behind**

```
protected void btnUpload_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            HiddenField hidnin = new HiddenField();
            hidnin = (HiddenField)gvdtaxes.Rows[2].FindControl("hidnin");

            txtapprovedby.Text = hidnin.Value;//always blank

//some code...
```

Comment: can you provide your code?

Comment: @ManishSharma code updated

Comment: Where do you bind data to the GridView? And on what page life cycle step? Please provide the code.

Comment: in page load event you can get the value if this hiddenfield.

Comment: @ManishSharma There is a radio button on whose checked event I bind this Gridview. Why can I not get the value of a HiddenField which is inside a Gridview on a button click event?\

Comment: Ensure that data was bound to GridView before button click event is handled.